# Using OSMnx to create graphs of informal settlements, where OSM data is not available

Tags: graph, shapefile

I have been able to create a graph successfully in the OSMnx platform from a edge and node shape file that I have complied for an informal settlement, from cadastral survey maps, in Dharavi, Mumbai as OSM data is not good in such cases. However while calculating basic stats of the graph I am getting **ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence**. Can you please advise on what could be wrong? I have added a screen shot of the graph and the error.

**[screen shot of the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JoSr.png)**

````py
G7 = ox.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs(dnodes_gdf, dedges_gdf, graph_attrs=None)```

```G7_projected = ox.project_graph(G7)
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G7_projected)```

```G7_proj = ox.project_graph(G7)
nodes_proj = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G7_proj, edges=False)
graph_area_m = nodes_proj.unary_union.convex_hull.area
graph_area_m```

```basic_stats = ox.basic_stats(G7)```

    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11988/668476885.py in <module>
----> 1 basic_stats = ox.basic_stats(G7)

~\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\stats.py in basic_stats(G, area, clean_int_tol, clean_intersects, tolerance, circuity_dist)
    346     stats["edge_length_avg"] = stats["edge_length_total"] / stats["m"]
    347     stats["streets_per_node_avg"] = streets_per_node_avg(G)
--> 348     stats["streets_per_node_counts"] = streets_per_node_counts(G)
    349     stats["streets_per_node_proportions"] = streets_per_node_proportions(G)
    350     stats["intersection_count"] = intersection_count(G)

~\.conda\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\stats.py in streets_per_node_counts(G)
     80     """
     81     spn_vals = list(streets_per_node(G).values())
---> 82     return {i: spn_vals.count(i) for i in range(int(max(spn_vals)) + 1)}
     83 
     84 

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
````

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal, reproducible code snippet for others to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks Geoff for replying. I have attached code snippets as well as a screen shots of the graph

Comment: Thanks Geoff for replying. I am attaching the code snippets and a screen shot of the graph

Comment: You have to run https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.stats.count_streets_per_node manually if you loaded shapefiles that lack this attribute necessary for calculating basic stats.